# error:ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I created a bus table and when I try to insert values in the table like:

```
 insert into bus values(&bus_no,&source, etc.,);
```

I get an error:

> ORA-01008 not all variables bound

Comment: you can use declare fetch method for this insert.

Comment: -1 That is not a useful question. A lot of information is missing. It is almost impossible not to find an answer to this question hen . This is the first answer I found.

Comment: There are a lot of error messages in the [Oracle 9i Error Messages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/toc.htm) manual  that i cannot find in the manuals or the alter releases. ORA-01008 is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `define` to set the values of the variables.

```
CREATE table t(col1 number, col2 number);

define n=4
insert into t values(1,&n)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c503/10)

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused by having more columns in the table then the columns that exist in your insert statement. You can resolve this by adding the missing columns to the values clause or by specifying the columns that you are inserting and making sure that you have the same number of columns as you do values bound to those columns.

```
insert into bus (bus_no, source, etc...) values(&bus_no,&source, etc.,);
```

Comment: +1 on specifying the column names in the insert statement: that way your code won't break when someone adds a column to the table.

Comment: -1 no, that is wrong. In this case the error is 'ORA-00947: not enough values', see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c503/1